# Convert a instance member function which uses this references, to static function

Tags: java, case-tools

I have a large non static **JAVA** function, which uses this reference at several places inside it. I want to convert it to static function and pass "this" reference as a parameter, so that I can take it to utility class.

Is there any tool which can automate this process?

**UPDATE**: Please share if some one has his own quick way of doing this(without using any tool).

Comment: Ctrl+F / Find: `this.` / Replace with: `param.` / Replace all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the method `myMethod` reside in the class `Foo`, and you need to make it static in the class `Util`.

1. Declare `private Foo foo;` in `Util`.
2. In Eclipse, use the Move refactoring on `myMethod`, choose `Util` as the target.
3. Add the `static` modifier to the moved method and fix the accesses to the added `Foo foo`'s internals.
4. Remove the `private Foo foo;` from `Util`.